# How to invoke my Actions on Google DRAFT from a phone?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

How can I test Actions on Google DRAFT on my android phone?

I have en-US language on phone, enabled all permissions and linked my account with Actions on Google. Simulator says I can test in on any device I logged in with my email, just LITERALLY SAYS that, but if I say "OK Google talk to my test app" it just show me google search, not invokes my draft.

- Do I need pass review stage for this?
- Or I need meet requirements of geolocation tat set in simulator?
- Maybe someone have clear guide to go through this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have tested the Action on the simulator - it should be available on any Android phone that has the Assistant using the same account. You don't need it reviewed while you are developing and testing it, and the location setting in the simulator is to send fake location information for testing.

Some things to look for:

- **Make sure you have tested it on the simulator *first*.** If you haven't done the "Talk to..." portion on the simulator, or if it doesn't work, it may not be available on your phone.
- **Make sure your phone is actually using the Google Assistant.** The older voice search for Android or Google Now aren't good enough. You may also not have turned it on. To turn it on for most phones:

  - Open the Google app and tap the menu in the upper left hand corner.
  - Select Settings.
  - Under "Google Assistant" select "Settings" and "Turn On"
- **Confirm you're using the same account in the simulator and in the Assistant on your phone.** You can see the account you're using in the simulator by clicking on the avatar icon in the upper right hand corner. On the phone, you can see the account you're using by:

  - Open the Assistant
  - Click the icon in the upper right hand corner of the window. It should be a blue dot with something that sorta looks like an inbox icon.

    (Something like this)

  [image]

  - Click the three vertical dot menu that appears in the upper right hand corner.
  - Select "Account"

Comment: The thing was I didn't realize OK google and assistant is different things... With assistant and Prisoner's instructions all work well.

Comment: If the answer helped, accepting it and/or an upvote are always appreciated.